# Observing attraction between parallel wires from two perspectives

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electric-current, inertial-frames, observers

Two parallel wires through which there flows a current in the same direction. While the electrons are moving, obviously the wires attract each other (the right hand rule for magnetism and electricity).

Now consider the following:

In my reference system, the electrons are not moving, as I am travelling with the speed of the electrons in the opposite direction of the current. What do I now observe? Do I still see the the wires attracting? Despite the electrons standing still, and there being no obvious source for either a magnetic-, or electric field which would result in mutual attraction. Or do I see the two wires repelling each other, as they should if the electrons are standing still? (equal charges repelling)

Imagine perhaps a second observer standing still relative to the wire, and not the electrons, this second observer would observe the wires attracting, perhaps simultaneously observing something which I am not.

Please help me understand this!

Comment: Now the protons are moving in the opposite direction.

Comment: if you are moving at the same speed as the electrons then you are not moving at the same speed as the protons.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oenU0OUGCH4

Answer (score 1):

In your new frame the electrons (which were moving --> in the old frame) are staying still and the protons (which were staying still) are moving <--

Comment: what if you accelerate the electrons before sending them through a tube. What now? There are no positive charges in the tube now, right?

Comment: @phywn8 You don't have parallel wires, then, do you? Now it's a completely different situation. It's parallel electron beams and they will repel each other regardless of velocity

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Electricity is basically charged particles in motion... Also, whenever a charged particle moves, it crerates a magnetic field: https://youtu.be/cd2Ua9dKEl8?t=51 Watch this video aswell:  youtube.com/watch?v=oenU0OUGCH4

Comment: @phywn8 Electrons have negative charges, which repel

Comment: that is right. But as far as I could tell, they don't create as strong of an electric field, as they do a magnetic one. Although, bottom line: still two charged parallel wires, and they should still attract, I just can't explain it from the electrons perspective.... without the positive charges...

Comment: In the lab frame, the positive charges make no magnetic field because they aren't moving. In the electron frame, the magnetic field has no effect on the stationary electrons. Magnetism is a fudge factor that corrects for frames where both charges move in directions where the electric field equation is fritzed.